# Unable to import owlready in Python

Tags: python, owl, owlready

I am trying to use the owlready library in Python. I downloaded the file from link(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Owlready) but when I am importing owlready I am getting following error:

```
>>> from owlready import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'owlready'
```

I tried running:

```
pip install owlready
```

I am get the error:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/owlready': Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you have `pip` installed in your box ? If yes and you're running a Gnu/Linux os, `sudo pip install Owlready`. And everything will be okay.

Comment: Where have you put `owlready`?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing it using `pip` instead.

Run the command `pip install <module name here>` to do so. If you are using python3, run `pip3 install <module name here>`.

If neither of these work you may also try:

`python -m pip install <module name here>`

or

`python3 -m pip install <module name here>`

If you don't yet have `pip`, you should probably get it. Very commonly used python package manager. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows) are some details on how to set the tool up.

Comment: I used the above command to install Owlready but I am getting error             error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/owlready': Permission denied

Comment: run it with sudo: `sudo python3 -m pip install <module name here>`

Comment: Great, if it solved your problem please mark this as the solution.

Answer (score -3):

You need installed library:

```
C:\PythonX.X\Scripts

    pip install owlready

Successfully installed Owlready-0.3
```